# Is there a recursive procedure for defining a polyhedron?

Tags: geometry

My observation is a polyhedron $H$ has a set of polygons, every polygon have many sides: take casually a polygon (or the first if i have a ordered list).

Define the following algorithm $f(n)$  where $n=3$ are dimensions as:

> 1. take a polygon ($n-1$ dimensional) $P$ in the polyhedron, check it is
>      closed using $f(n-1)$ on $P$ and put $P$ inside the set $S=\{P\}$.
> 2. for each side ($n-2$) dimensional $(a,b)$ of this polygon $P$, find the other polygon $P'$ of ipothetic polyhedron sharing the same side (I obtain so another polygon) such as $P'$ is not in $S$ and put $P'$ in $S$.
> 3. recursively repeat point 2. until no $P'$ is found.
> 4. $H$ is a polyhedron if and only if every $(n-2)$ d side $(a,b)$ found in the navigation is shared between $2$ polygons $n-1$ dimensional

Is there a similar algorythm or a similar mathematical definition in the literature ?

My ipotheis is if i am in space $n$-dimensional, i can check a closed convex solid shapes using $f(n-1), f(n-2) ...f(3)$  . Probably it would be better replace polygon and polyhedrom with convex polytope k-dimensional.
This algorythm hightlights that the minimum dimension number for applying this one is n>=3.It makes to think about reality and why is equals 3? :)

Comment: What exactly is this "algorythm" supposed to accomplish?

Comment: it is my question. I m searching if exist a recursive algorythm for defining a polygon. My preface is just a intuition on the fly i got. I m searching if exist a solid mathematical definition touching my intuition. This algorythm could have the feature to compress the polyhedron rappresentation(normally there are many ripetition in points). Based on this intuition and his abstraction over higher levels is possible also to define a new  abstract shapes , never heard by me. By i m not a mathematician

Comment: Probably there are many.

Comment: You might have  a look here: [convex polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#Intersection_of_half-spaces)

Comment: What do *you* define as a polygon?

Comment: yes you are right, it would be more precise to use a same recursive definition for polygon and polyhedron, it would be necessary introduce a unique new definition for both.I discovered now there is probably polytope for that definition